# Differential Equations Model a 401k

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Your employer automatically puts 15 percent of your salary into a 401(k) retirement account each year. The account earns 9% interest. Suppose you just got the job, your starting salary is $30000, and you expect to receive a 2% raise each year.

For simplicity, assume that interest earned and your raises occur continuously.

Model this and then find the value of your retirement account after 35 years

I got 
$$.09y + 4500 \cdot 1.02^{t}e^{0.09t}$$
which would give me

Is this correct? Am I in the ballpark? I got a y because its .09 of the previous balance but that makes this recursive and I don't think it's supposed to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It helps to work systematically.  Let $t$ be the time in years, $s(t)$ your salary at time $t$, and $b(t)$ the balance in your account at time $t$  We are given: $$s'(t)=0.02 s(t)\\b'(t)=0.09b(t)+0.15s(t)\\s(0)=30000,b(0)=0$$
Now solve the first to get $s(t)$ and plug into the second.  Can you do that?